# How to add where condition if result count is greater than one

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to build SQL query that returns unique id.
My problem is that i need to add another condition to query if i have more than one result.

```
select u.id
from users u
where u.id in ('1','2','3')
and u.active = 'Y'
```

if i get more than one result i need to add:

```
and u.active_contact = 'Y'
```

I tried to build this query

```
select * from (
select u.id, count(u.id) as results
from users u
where u.id in ('1','2','3')
and u.active = 'Y'
group by u.id
) tab
If(tab.results > 1) then
    where tab.u.active_contact = 'Y'
end
```

Thanks in advanced.

Hope i explained my self good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach:

```
SELECT id
  FROM (SELECT id, (CASE WHEN active ='Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN active_contact ='Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as actv FROM users ORDER BY actv DESC)
  WHERE actv > 0
  LIMIT 1
```

The subquery adds a column which aggregates `active` and `active_contact`. The main `SELECT` then optimizes the combination of these two fields, requiring at least one of them. I believe this provides the intended result.

Answer (score 0):

Among the possible ways to solve this, here are two.

1) Use the active_contact id. If there is none use another id.

```
select coalesce( max(case when active_contact = 'Y' then id end), max(id) ) as id
from users
where id in ('1','2','3')
and active = 'Y';
```

2) Sort with active_contact coming first. Then get the first record.

```
select id
from
(
  select id
  from users
  where id in ('1','2','3')
  and active = 'Y'
  order by case when active_contact = 'Y' then 1 else 2 end
) where rownum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

A method using Analytic functions

```
SELECT id
FROM (SELECT u.id
           , u.active_contact
           , count(*) OVER () actives
      FROM users u
      WHERE u.id IN ('1','2','3')
      AND u.active = 'Y')
WHERE (  actives = 1
      OR (   actives > 1
         AND active_contact = 'Y'))
```

If there is more than one record where `active = 'Y' AND active_contact = 'Y'` it will return them all. If only one of these is required you will need to identify the criteria for choosing that one.